# Network byte order to host byte order

Tags: c, networking, bitwise, integer

While doing a little project involving sniffing packets, I found myself programming a **cross platform** network to host byte order and host to network byte order, this is my first time developing a project using networking.

## ntboc.h

```
#ifndef NTBOC_H_INCLUDED
#define NTBOC_H_INCLUDED

#define LITTLE_EDIAN    1
#define BIG_EDIAN       2

// convert from host to network byte order
void ntboc_tont(void *data, size_t len);
//convert from network to host byte order
#define ntboc_toht(data, len)   (ntboc_tont(data,len))
#endif
```

## ntboc.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ntboc.h"

static unsigned int ntbo = 0;

static void ntboc_init()
{
    int t = 1;
    if(*((char *)&t))
        ntbo = LITTLE_EDIAN;
    else
        ntbo = BIG_EDIAN;
}

static void ntboc_swap(void *data, size_t len)
{
    size_t off = len-1;

    unsigned char *ddata = data;
    unsigned char *sdata = data + off;
    unsigned char tmp;

    while((void *)sdata > (data + (off)/2)) {
        tmp = *ddata;
        *ddata = *sdata;        
        *sdata = tmp;

        sdata--, ddata++;
    }

}

void ntboc_tont(void *data, size_t len) 
{
    if(ntbo == 0)
        ntboc_init();

    if(ntbo == BIG_EDIAN)
        return;

    ntboc_swap(data, len);
}

main()
{
    short len = 0x3e;
    ntboc_toht(&len, 2);
    printf("len : %x", len);
}
```

Comment: It's ["endian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), not "edian".

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your approach is that your are trying to simultaneously satisfy two contradictory requirements: produce a robust cross-platform implementation, and explicitly deal with different hosts.

A better approach is to avoid any knowledge of the host's endianness by using shifts and or's. It is, however, perfectly fine to rely on network byte order being big-endian as that is an invariant.

Consider the conversion to network order first. This is the simpler direction as it is always fixed but, in C at least, you will need to write routines to deal with the different sizes of int. For now, we will deal with `unsigned int` only.

```
void uint_to_network(unsigned int value, unsigned char * buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    size_t nw_length = sizeof(value);

    if (buffer_size < nw_length) return; // Avoid potential overflow

    // Note that this loops until all possible locations in the
    // output stream are filled, automatically handling leading zeroes.
    while(nw_length != 0)
    {
        // Pre-decrementing nw_length deals with the zero-based nature
        // of C arrays and avoids us having to worry about the representation
        // of -1 as an unsigned value.
        nw_length--;
        buffer[nw_length] = value & 0xff;
        value >>= 8;
    }
}
```

Note that this code is written in terms of the network order, with no knowledge of the host's endianness. Thus, it is inherently cross-platform.

Converting from network to host follows a similar pattern.

```
unsigned int network_to_uint(unsigned char * buffer, size_t input_length)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    size_t decode_length;

    decode_length = (input_length > sizeof(unsigned int)) 
                      ? sizeof(unsigned int)
                      : input_length;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < decode_length; i++)
    {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= (unsigned int) buffer[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Again, the code is written in terms of the known network order and makes no reliance on the host order.

Also note that, whenever dealing with network side data, I always use the `unsigned char` format. This is because network data is basically a 'bit stream', and you should never try to deal with it as a different native data type. That way lies madness .. or at least very subtle bugs.

Now, in a production implementation where execution speed is all important, you would actually have two implementations of the routines. On a big-endian host they would be no-ops, or at worst a macro performing a cast. On a little-endian host, they would be heavily optimized based on the knowledge that conversion was always required. Then your build-script would link in the set of routines that made sense for the target: and you **would** have some intelligence in the build script if only to select the correct target-processor for the cross compiler.

But for a true cross-platform single-implementation solution, avoiding knowledge of the host's endianness is the only sure route to avoiding problems.

By the way, if you change the return type of `network_to_uint` to `unsigned long long` (or `unsigned long` if your compiler is too old for `long long`) it can deal with all of the unsigned integer types in the network data by passing in the correct value for `input_length`. But you will still need a different routine to deal with signed data. And remember that, for an `unsigned int` in the network data you need to specify the correct input length. A network `int` may not be the same size as your host's.

For signed data, you have to be a little more careful. There are hosts out there which store data with a separate sign bit (i.e. they can represent both positive and negative zero) and C is designed to run on those as well.

And really, my `uint_to_network` has the fault that it assumes `sizeof(unsigned int)` on the host is the same as its representation in a network data stream. It really ought to take an `output_length` argument instead of setting `nw_length` to `sizeof(unsigned int)`. Then it can also be made to work for all unsigned data, because it only extracts the least significant bytes of the data.